# locationManager.getBestProvider

Tags: android, gps, location, location-provider

I'm working on an application which uses location.

My problem:
When I'm looking for the best provider, I only get the "network".
I know why but I don't know how to improve this.
In the locations settings, when I check "parameter -> location" and "security settings -> Use wireless network", the `LocationManager.getBestProvider()` returns only network. When it is not checked, and the GPS is active, `getBestProvider` returns the GPS.

What I want to do is:
When both options are checked, how to use / detect the GPS, instead of the network, as the location provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first check whether GPS is on or not. If it is on then get the location from GPS, if not get the location from network.
To check the gps status use :

```
manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
boolean statusOfGPS = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Comment: Thanks Maneesh,
But, is during the application is running, the gps status is disabled, stopped, or the satellite connexion is not well,
the statusOfGPS will be false ?

Comment: no statusof GPS will always true if gps is on but you can get the location by gpslocationlistener , if staellite is not giving the location then you can use LastGapLocation, and also GPS location is  accurate than network location. May be some 10-20 meters location difference is always very in gps location

Comment: Ok, see what you mean, but my last question will be : 
How to detect if the satellite not giving the location ?
in my code, i have those lines in the onGpsStatusChanged(event): 
switch (event)
    {
    case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
      
      break;
    case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
      
      break;
    case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
     
      break;
    case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
      break;
}
in this, I can detect if i receive something by satellits, but, if i'm not receiving something, i will never been in this case?
it isnt?

Comment: yes if phones gps is manually getting off then GPS_EVENT_STOPPED will be fired then statusOfGPS will be false then only you have to go fo network location .